# Return just data in BQ CLI with query no "Welcome to BigQuery!" etc output

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am using the gcloud cli to query Big Query.

Example:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --format json 'select * from `ga4-extract.analytics_123456789.events_20220722` limit 1;' > data.json
```

After running this, if I cat data.json I see my data, but above the data in the file is the following text:

```
root@9e4947a68356:/# cat data.json 

Welcome to BigQuery! This script will walk you through the 
process of initializing your .bigqueryrc configuration file.

First, we need to set up your credentials if they do not 
already exist.

Setting project_id data-extract as the default.

BigQuery configuration complete! Type "bq" to get started.
```

Then my data appears underneath in desired json format. How can I get rid of this text so it does not show? Tried the following flags after reading [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference), in each case no difference, the above output was still added to my data.json file:

- --batch=true
- --quiet=true
- --headless=true

How can I save my output to data.json without the text above at the top of the json file?

Comment: Try swallowing stderr: `2> /dev/null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do another command which will create this output the first type...
For example in your case :

bq show ga4-extract.analytics_123456789

will show some little information about your dataset and will also create this .biqqueryrc file... Your next command will not have this in the output.